# How do I configure proxy and proxy authentication in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, linux-mint

Online there are many post which tell different ways to add proxy in Linux . but i want to know best way add proxy and proxy authentication in Linux specially Linux mint . because i already try /`etc/apt/apt.conf` to add or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/environment`  but my terminal doesn't connect so does Firefox . there are network setting option where we can proxy that also doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using `.ovpn` file?

Comment: @GAD3R       no , i don't

Comment: can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf`?

Comment: Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";  same as for https,ftp& sock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 : Open a terminal window and type the following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

2 : Copy the following lines in your `/etc/environment` file and modify accordingly.

```
 http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
 https_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
 ftp_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
 no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"    
 HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
 HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/     
 FTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/   
 NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

3 : save your changes and log-out and log-in.

4 : If your `apt-get` command is still not able to access internet,execute

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies
```

and copy the following lines and modify accordingly

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port/";    
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@proxy:port/";   
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@proxy:port/";
```

5 : once again save your changes and log-out and log-in.

P.S : You may have to delete `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/environment`.  It is not a place to store the environment variables. Moreover there is no such file on my system.

Comment: still no connection